# tensorflow error: ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer expected axis -1

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to modify code provided to me to import a image file and build a training and test set using keras.
I am receiving the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-b4983c6bd066> in <module>()
      1 # Fit the model
----> 2 history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 256, epochs = 15, verbose=2, validation_data=(X_test,y_test))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    821       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    822       initializers = []
--> 823       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    824     finally:
    825       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    695     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    696         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 697             *args, **kwds))
    698 
    699     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2853       args, kwargs = None, None
   2854     with self._lock:
-> 2855       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2856     return graph_function
   2857 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3073             arg_names=arg_names,
   3074             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3075             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3076         self._function_attributes,
   3077         function_spec=self.function_spec,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    598         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    599         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 600         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    601     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    602 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\synar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\synar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\synar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\synar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\synar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\synar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\synar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:747 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    C:\Users\synar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:976 __call__
        self.name)
    C:\Users\synar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\input_spec.py:216 assert_input_compatibility
        ' but received input with shape ' + str(shape))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_41 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784 but received input with shape [None, 1]
```

My code I have implemented so is:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn import model_selection
from scipy.io import loadmat

data = loadmat('notMNIST_small.mat')
X_temp = data['images']/255

#for i in range(X_temp.shape[2]):
    
X = np.empty(shape=[X_temp.shape[2]] + [784], dtype='float32')
for i in range(X_temp.shape[2]):
    X[i,:] = X_temp[:,:,i].flatten()

y = pd.get_dummies(data['labels']).to_numpy()

print(X_temp.shape)
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
X[1,:]

X = np.array(data['labels']).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array(data['labels'])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=9)

stdscaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_train_scaled = stdscaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled  = stdscaler.transform(X_test)

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2, l1
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

# Stochastic Logistic Regression
model = Sequential()

# Model
model.add(Dense(units=10, input_shape = [784,], activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0)))
model.add(Dense(units = 40, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = 10, activation = 'sigmoid'))
# Compile model
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)
```

I get the error when implementing the following cell:

```
# Fit the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 256, epochs = 15, verbose=2, validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
```

Any help in resolving this would be great I am new to machine learning so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: could you show the shape of X, y

Comment: You are reinitialising the X value and storing the labels instead of actual images value

Comment: @RishabhJain Could you elaborate on the this? How would I find the shape of X and Y? The code I am using was taken directly from another workbook I had where it worked fine. The only thing I changed was X = np.array(data['labels']).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array(data['labels'])

Comment: data['labels'] is you result array which should be stored in y.
But you are storing it in X as well. so when you are fitting your model you are only passing labels not the actual data. and that's the reason above error has occurred

Please share the link from where you took the code

Comment: @RishabhJain Thank you for clarifying.  Here is the link to the notebook and files used there are some other csv's thats related to a different notebook. [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1--98LzAhzrRGSyjH0pOZzY31SQ2KBT4H?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Add extra dimension to your X_train as

```
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 28*28)

model = Sequential()

# Model
model.add(Dense(units=10, input_dim = 784, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0)))
model.add(Dense(units = 40, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = 10, activation = 'sigmoid'))
# Compile model
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)
```